# Why doesn't my Django template render a ModelForm's id or pk field?

Tags: django, forms, django-templates

In Django 1.10, I'm prepopulating a ModelForm in a template using a record from the database in order to edit that record in the form. However, when I want to render the HTML for the form, it doesn't show the `id` (or `pk`) fields. I want to put the id in a hidden <input> tag so when the form submits the backend knows which record to edit when the form is submitted. My web app doesn't have the id in the URL.

Here is my models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

In the database, I've added one MyModel record with name `'Alice'` and phone `'212-555-5555'`. The id/primary key is `1`.

Here is my forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from . import models

class TestForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.MyModel
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'phone']
```

Here is my views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from . import forms, models

def test_page(request):
    m = models.MyModel.objects.get(name='Alice')
    prepopulatedForm = forms.TestForm(instance=m)
    return render(request, 'testproject/test_template.html', {'form': prepopulatedForm})
```

Here is my test_template.html:

```
<h1>Test Page</h1>
{{ form }}
```

This renders the form on the page, prepopulated with `'Alice'` and `'212-555-5555'`:

```
<h1>Test Page</h1>
<tr><th><label for="id_name">Name:</label></th><td><input id="id_name" maxlength="50" name="name" type="text" value="Alice" required /></td></tr>
<tr><th><label for="id_phone">Phone:</label></th><td><input id="id_phone" maxlength="50" name="phone" type="text" value="212-555-5555" required /></td></tr>
```

My question is, why doesn't the id / primary key column appear in this form? I can't get it to render when I use this for the template either:

```
<h1>Test Page</h1>
{{ form.id }}
{{ form.name }}
{{ form.phone }}
```

This renders a blank where the id <input> should be:

```
<h1>Test Page</h1>

<input id="id_name" maxlength="50" name="name" type="text" value="Alice" required />
<input id="id_phone" maxlength="50" name="phone" type="text" value="212-555-5555" required />
```

I can see from running `python manage.py shell` that the record is in fact there:

```
>>> from testproject import models
>>> m = models.MyModel.objects.get(name='Alice')
>>> m.id
1
```

In forms.py, setting `fields` to `['id', 'name', 'phone']` doesn't cause any errors, nor does `['pk', 'name', 'phone']`. However, if I purposefully add a non-existent field name like `['NOT_REAL_FIELD', 'name', 'phone']`, then `python manage.py runserver` will produce an error:

```
  File "C:\Users\Al\venvs\tas_env\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py", line 257, in __new__
    raise FieldError(message)
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (NOT_REAL_FIELD) specified for MyModel
```

So I know that `'id'`/`'pk'` must be a legitimate field to put in the ModelForm.

Why doesn't my Django template render a ModelForm's id or pk field?

Eventually, I'd like to include the primary key as a hidden input in the form so that the record in the database can be edited. Also note, I don't care about ModelAdmin since I'm trying to display this in a template viewable by users, not in the admin panel. It's fine that the pk is read-only; it just needs to render in the template.

Comment: Why do you want the id field to be editable? In Django the usual approach is to include the id in the url e.g. `/mymodel/<pk>/`, then fetch the object to be edited in the view e.g. `MyModel.objects.get(pk=pk)`.

Comment: I want to put the pk in a hidden &lt;input&gt; tag so when the form submits the backend knows which record to edit when the form is submitted. My URLs don't have the pk of <user's thing>, but are rather "/<user>/<user's thing>". Will I have to use these two bits of info to retrieve the record?

Answer (score 8):

How about accessing the id using `{{ form.initial.id }}`?

From what I can tell in looking the ModelForm metaclass, `form.initial` is populated a bit differently than the creation of form properties (e.g. `form.name` or `form.phone`). So basically it is in the weeds of the django metaclass [magic](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/models.py)...

To be a bit more specific. It appears that when creating a form, `model_to_dict` is called to pull data out of the model instance that is passed in. But it isn't until `fields_for_model` is called that the form instance has the model fields accessible as class attributes. I would guess that `id` is somehow being excluded from the fields being considered in `fields_for_model`. It looks like the non-editable field exception you referenced is raised here as well.

Comment: This does work! Oddly, `{{ form.initial.pk }}` is blank. Though this doesn't answer my original question, it is a slightly nicer workaround than my current workaround.

What do I google to find out what `.initial` is? Is it related to "dynamic initial values" or is it another concept? I'd like to find out what is the best practice for rendering a PK in a template.

Comment: Just added a touch more info. I was able to get a rough sense from looking through the ModelForm source code, specifically the metaclass section.

Answer (score 4):

Late answer, but may help others:

```
{{ form.instance.id }}
```

This works for me

Answer (score 3):

The `id` field automatically has `editable=False`, which means by default it doesn't show up in any model forms.

There is no need to put the id in a hidden field, though. If you go to a URL to edit an object, and that URL displays a form, it should submit back to the same URL - in which case you still have the id in the URL.

Comment: I don't think this is it. When I set `editable=False` on the `name` or `phone` fields, I get an error message as soon as I run `python manage.py runserver`:

`django.core.exceptions.FieldError: 'phone' cannot be specified for MyModel model form as it is a non-editable field`

I don't get this error with the `id` or `pk` fields.

Comment: In my web app's case, I'm not using the primary key in URL. The url is /<user>/<thing>, instead of using the user's thing's id, so getting it from the URL isn't possible.