# access to pk in a template form

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I want to display all elements of a form including the pk and I have not found a satisfying method to do so:

```
class SomeForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields["number"] = forms.IntegerField(required = True)
        self.fields["id"] = forms.IntegerField(disabled = True)
        self.fields["data"] = forms.CharField(required = False)
        
    class Meta:
        model = SomeModel
        fields = ["id", "number", "data"]
```

So now I just call the form in the view with:

```
class SomeView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "app/sometemplate.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        obj = MODEL.objects.get(pk = context["pk"])
        MODEL_data = {}
        MODEL_data["number"] = obj.number
        MODEL_data["id"] = obj.pk
        MODEL_data["data"] = obj.data

        context["form"] = SomeForm(initial = MODEL_data)
        return context
```

and now in the templatetags I have a filter `get_pk`:

```
@register.filter(name='get_pk')
def get_pk(obj):
    return obj.initial["id"]
```

and I get the `pk` in the template with `{{ form|get_pk }}` and I feel like this is not smart. I tried stuff like `{{ form.instance.id }}` like suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68054522/4225972). I still feel there must be an easy way to achieve this?

Comment: `pk` already exists in the context, you use it to get the object via `context["pk"]`, use that `{{ pk }}`?

Comment: Ones should not code tired. This is exactly right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you need form in template view? You just need to get the context no more..
There are many comments in shared code like:

1-Disabled id field in initial form

2-Using different model name in form and get context data

3-Filtering context by using context["pk"] before assessing obj

Find the revised code,

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context["obj"] = SomeModel.objects.get(pk = the desired value)
    return context
```

Note: if you want user to insert pk then you can use input field inside form with get method and get its value inside get context data in this way:
context["pk"] = self.request.GET.get("name of input field ")

In template html you can display fields directly:
{{obj.id}},{{obj.name}}, {{obj.data}}

Comment: I actually did what @Iain Shelvington proposed but your's is also correct and he did not post an answer.